# The output window closes after entering the input in C

Tags: c++, c

I wrote program in C , but after compiling and running it the output console does not stay on after I enter anything. My program requires to enter distance and time.

My code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int spd(int x , int y);
int main() {
       int x,y;
       printf("enter the distance first then time in their SI units  :\n");
       scanf("%d",&x);
       scanf("%d",&y);
       printf("the speed required is ",spd(x,y));
       getch();
       return 0;
 }
 int spd(int x , int y) {
       return x/y;
 }
```

Comment: `scanf("%d";&x);` That can't be right. There's a `;` inside the statement.

Comment: `;` in `scanf()`, no `%d` in `printf`?

Comment: yeah you are right , i did not see that , a typing ,mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including this header file : -

```
#include conio.h
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the getch feeds on your input-buffer. When you enter your value in `scanf()`, the '\n' remains.

Try to put `flush(stdin)` after your `scanf()` or for now put `getch ()` twice.

Comment: hey it is not scant()but it is scanf().

Comment: Note that `fflush(stdin)` is not defined by the C standard, but Windows does define the behaviour (whereas Unix does not).

Comment: scanf("%d%*c",&x); Then you dont need any of that =D

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run a console program, you should run it from a console. You have written a console program -- run it from a console.

Also, you need to either flush standard out or write a newline before the `getch` call. Otherwise, you're waiting for a keypress before you've actually written anything.